# No visible @interface for meal declares the selector calculatetip

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, methods

i'm trying to call a method from another class and can't quite seem to get it to work.  Trying suggestions from other threads, but even after seems to just throw the same error. Language is objective C 
Source for Meal.h

```
@interface Meal : NSObject
- (float)CalculateTip:(float)MealCost secondValue:(float)SelectedValue;

@end
```

Source for Meal.m

```
#import "Meal.h"

@implementation Meal
- (float) CalculateTip:(float)MealCost secondValue:(float)SelectedValue
{
float finalVal = 0;
float tipval = 0;
if (SelectedValue == 0)
{
    tipval = .1;
}
else if (SelectedValue == 1)
{
    tipval = .15;
}
else if (SelectedValue == 2)
{
    tipval = .2;
}
finalVal = MealCost*tipval;
return finalVal;
}

@end
```

Import statements in ViewController class

```
    #import "Meal.h";
```

Calling the method
        `Meal *meal = [[Meal alloc] init];`

This is where the error occurs "No visible @interface for meal declares the selector calculatetip"

```
float finalFloat =  [meal CalculateTip:MealCostFloat:select];
```

Comment: Name your method starting with a lower case, same for the parameters. `[meal CalculateTip:MealCostFloat secondValue:select];`? Also don't import "Meal.m".

Comment: You've posted a bunch a code and referenced a fake error in the title. Please update your question by pointing out where exactly you see an error and post the real, actual, and complete error message.

Comment: And to reiterate, do not import .m files. That's just not right.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared a method named `CalculateTip:secondValue:`.

But you attempt to call it as:

```
[meal CalculateTip:MealCostFloat:select];
```

It needs to be something like:

```
[mean CalculateTip:firstValue secondValue:theOtherValue];
```

where `firstValue` and `theOtherValue` are two variables or constants that you need to pass to the method.

Perhaps your two values are `MealCostFloat` and `select`. It's hard to tell.

```
[mean CalculateTip:MealCostFloat secondValue:select];
```

And, as mentioned in the comments, standard naming conventions is that method and variable names begin with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase letters.

And don't import .m file, just .h files.

One last thing. Given how you use the `SelectedValue` parameter's value, I'd suggest changing its type from `float` to `int`.

```
- (float)calculateTip:(float)mealCost secondValue:(int)selectedValue
{
    float tipval = 0;
    if (selectedValue == 0)
    {
        tipval = .1;
    }
    else if (selectedValue == 1)
    {
        tipval = .15;
    }
    else if (selectedValue == 2)
    {
        tipval = .2;
    }

    float finalVal = mealCost * tipval;

    return finalVal;
}
```